# Easiest way to trackback recursive calls?

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

I wrote a recursive DP solution to a problem. The solution is failing for some test cases (It's over-counting or undercounting just a single turn). How can I  trackback or print only those states that led to my final answer?

The recursive function is something like this. It takes in 4 inputs. If a particular state has been evaluated before, it returns the solution from `std::map` else it evaluates it. The solution recursively returns the `min` value for every state.

This is an attempt to solve [Play the Dragon](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/5304486/dashboard#s=p2) of [Google CodeJam 2017 1A](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/5304486/dashboard)

```
int hd,ad,hk,ak,b,d;
int inf=1e9+1;
map< tuple<int,int,int,int>, int > dp;

int count(int hld, int hlk, int atd, int atk){
  if(dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)]){
    return dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)];
  }
  else{
    if(hlk<=0){
      return 0;
    }
    if(hld<=0){
      return inf;
    }
    if(hlk-atd<=0){
      return 1;
    }
    if(hld==hd-atk){
      if(b==0||d==0){
        if(b==0&&d!=0){
          return dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)] = 1 + min(
                                                           count(hld-atk,hlk-atd,atd,atk),
                                                           count(hld-atk+d,hlk,atd,(atk-d)<0?0:(atk-d))
                                                           );
        }
        if(b!=0&&d==0){
          return dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)] = 1 + min(
                                                           count(hld-atk,hlk-atd,atd,atk),
                                                           count(hld-atk,hlk,atd+b,atk)
                                                           );
        }
        return dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)] = 1 + count(hld-atk,hlk-atd,atd,atk);
      }
      return dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)] = 1 + min(
                                                       count(hld-atk,hlk-atd,atd,atk),
                                                       min(
                                                           count(hld-atk,hlk,atd+b,atk),
                                                           count(hld-atk+d,hlk,atd,(atk-d)<0?0:(atk-d))
                                                           )
                                                       );
    }
    if(b==0||d==0){
      if(b==0&&d!=0){
        if(atk<=0){
          return dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)] = 1 + count(hld-atk,hlk-atd,atd,atk);
        }
        return dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)] = 1 + min(
                                                         count(hld-atk,hlk-atd,atd,atk),
                                                         min(
                                                             count(hd-atk,hlk,atd,atk),
                                                             count(hld-atk+d,hlk,atd,(atk-d)<0?0:(atk-d))
                                                             )
                                                         );
      }
      if(b!=0&&d==0){
        return dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)] = 1 + min(
                                                         count(hld-atk,hlk-atd,atd,atk),
                                                         min(
                                                             count(hld-atk,hlk,atd+b,atk),
                                                             count(hd-atk,hlk,atd,atk)
                                                             )
                                                         );
      }
      if(atk<=0){
        return dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)] = 1 + count(hld-atk,hlk-atd,atd,atk);
      }
      return dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)] = 1 + min(
                                                       count(hld-atk,hlk-atd,atd,atk),
                                                       count(hd-atk,hlk,atd,atk)
                                                       );
    }

    if(atk<=0){
      return dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)] = 1 + min(
                                                       count(hld-atk,hlk-atd,atd,atk),
                                                       count(hld-atk,hlk,atd+b,atk)
                                                       );
    }
    return dp[make_tuple(hld,hlk,atd,atk)] = 1 + min(
                                                     count(hld-atk,hlk-atd,atd,atk),
                                                     min(
                                                         count(hld-atk,hlk,atd+b,atk),
                                                         min(
                                                           count(hd-atk,hlk,atd,atk),
                                                           count(hld-(atk-d)<0?0:(atk-d),hlk,atd,(atk-d)<0?0:(atk-d))
                                                         )
                                                         )
                                                     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy method would be keeping the parent tuple in the map along with the computed value, i.e. if T is your tuple you use `std::map <T, std::pair<int, T>>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there can be a solution to your wish but it is not straightforward at all and implementing it you can introduce more problems or errors in your code than there are now (I suggest their presence because you don't achieve the right answer). The idea is to mark any new function call with a unique id and data stored somewhere globally. When the function is called, it should have information about its parent id and create own id to pass to all branches it is going to call. When it finishes it writes her id to parent id data cell with the result. You have only one place in your functions for branching - when you calculate min of two counts. So you need to put in parent id data cell both call results with ids to compare in the future analasys. Thus you create a structure of calls which on it's own is not informative at all. The main thing is to add to parent id some additional information - which branch was choosen (I meand, you have 15 return statements and 2 variants of choices inside them - I think you want to know what was chosen). For any chosen branch you and to id field chosen flag. By this flag when your calculation finish you will go from id to id throght your data and write on screen only "chosen" ones call data. Good luck!